# WPF - Bind a ListView to a .xml file dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, data-binding, listview

Is there a way (using the MVVM pattern) to dynamically bind a ListView to an xml file?
Actually the ListView is binded to a static path, like:

```
C:\DocumentsAndSettings\blabla\morebla\log.xml
```

I need something like

```
AppPath\log.xml
```

Here's my code:
in the View.xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource logDataSource}, ...
```

in the App.xaml:

```
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="logDataSource" 
                     Source="C:\DocumentsAndSettings\blabla\morebla\log.xml" 
                     d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

I'd like something like this:

```
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="logDataSource" 
                     Source="AppPath\log.xml" 
                     d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use relative paths? For example, if you put your `log.xml` in data directory in your project, simply write

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="logDataSource" Source="data/log.xml" />
```

Note that the file should have a `build action` of `"resource"`.
Or if it's a `"content"` then set `copy to o/p directory` to `"copy always"`.
(Search for difference b/w these two on Google)

Comment: In your case it seems that you have put `log.xml` in the root of project. So try `<XmlDataProvider x:Key="logDataSource" Source="log.xml" />`

Answer (score 0):

If I put the log.xml file in my project directory, the logger library will write in the

```
project/bin/debug/log.xml
```

while the xaml binding will look for log.xml in

```
project/log.xml
```

I solved the problem setting the property of the log.xml file to "Content" not to "Resource"..even if I really don't know the difference :)