# WPF - ListView xml Bindign works only once

Tags: wpf, xml, listview

I have a ListView Binded to an xml file (a simple log file).

This list view is in a secondary dialog Window in my project.

When I open the window for the first time it shows the info in the list view correctly. Then, if I close this window and do some stuff, my xml file changes. If now I reopen the dialog Window containing the xml file, it shows the last status (the info showed the firs time I opened the window), not the whole status with updates.

Why??

Answer (score 1):

The XML doesn't trigger the INotifyPropertyChanged events that WPF databinding relies on to know when items change and need to be re-bound. You may want to set the ItemsSource or DataContext explicitly each time you open the dialog window.

Also, the XML objects don't detect file changes. You may need to reload the XML if you are relying on outside events (system logs?) to create the new XML nodes.

Comment: oh, thank you. Strange..I don't understand why if I close a Window the ItemSource remain setted..anyway: how can I reset the ItemSource?

Comment: By 'reset' ItemsSource/DataContext do you mean 'reassign'?  Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what will fix your problem because your description is imprecise.  You say:

> I have a ListView Binded to an xml file (a simple log file).

and this is not actually possible.  You can't bind a `ListView`, only its `ItemsSource`.  And you can't bind to an XML file, but only to an object in memory that contains the data read from the XML file.  This sounds like I'm picking nits, but I'm not:  the clearer you are in describing what you're actually doing, the easier it will be to provide you with a usable answer.

It sounds as though you probably are defining an `XmlDataProvider` in XAML with its `Source` set to the name of the XML file.  If you set this as a resource in your main window, it's going to be loaded when the main window is loaded.  If your child window has something like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyXmlDocument}" .../>
```

it's going to look up the `XmlDataProvider` using the resource dictionary's `Find` method, and find it in the main window's resource dictionary.  You can close and reopen the child window all day long and the `XmlDataProvider` it uses won't change.

If this is the case, what you probably need is one of two things.

First, you could move the definition of the `XmlDataProvider` resource to the child window's XAML.  That will force the child window to reload the XML every time the child window loads.

Second, you could add a method to the main window that recreates the `XmlDataProvider` whenever the XML file changes on disk.  (How you know when the XML file changes, and how you trigger the method in the main window, are relatively tricky problems to solve - you could use `FileSystemWatcher` events, for instance.)  You'd need to use the `DynamicResource` markup extension in your child window XAML if you do this.) That will refresh the child window every time the XML file changes - even if it's already open.

Comment: mmmh...now I'm understanding. Exactly I have the ItemSource bindend to an XmlDataProvider defined in the app.xaml. I tried to define the xmldatasource in the child win's XAML but I have problem with the file used as resource/content. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416918/wpf-bind-a-listview-to-a-xml-file-dynamically